# Kivy App gives "Singular Matrix" error on phone, but not on computer

Tags: ios, xcode, numpy, kivy

I've encountered an issue with my self-written Kivy app, that I haven't found anywhere online Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The issue is as follows. My code involves numpy matrix inversion and works absolutely fine when I run it on my computer. But as soon as I run it either on a simulated iPhone in XCode, or on my personal phone, I get a `LinAlgError("Singular matrix") numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` error, even though the matrix in question is definitely not singular.

EDIT:

**On Computer:**

Numpy version:  `1.19.1`
Output of `numpy.show_config()`:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

**On simulated phone:**

Numpy version: `1.16.4`
Output of `numpy.show_config()`:

```
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_clapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
accelerate_info:
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

Comment: Further experiments with numpy.linalg and kivy-ios seem to suggest thst linalg just doesn't seem to work at all after creating the app with the toolchain. Even computing the determinant of a benign 2x2 matrix gives completely false results...

Comment: What numpy version? What does `numpy.show_config()` give on the phone vs the computer?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the info you requested

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your issue is almost certainly the `-Wl,Accelerate` in your linker args. Accelerate ships with a very old and somewhat broken version of LAPACK, which is why as of https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/15759 (unreleased 1.20) it is no longer supported at all.

If you can rebuild kivy's numpy with `ATLAS=None BLAS=None LAPACK=None` set in your environment variables, you'll end up without this Accelerate dependency.

You may have to dig around starting at https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes/numpy/__init__.py to work out how to pass this into kivy.

Comment: Thanks for that! Where and how do I set the environment variables? I'm just beginning with Kivy. Are `ATLAS=None BLAS=None LAPACK=None` options in `toolchain build ...`?

Comment: If you're lucky, you can just just use `ATLAS=None BLAS=None LAPACK=None toolchain build ...`. I've never used kivy, so you may have more luck on their issue tracker.

Comment: But is it even possible that the old version of numpy.linalg was THAT bad? In the above example, it was basically impossible to find any matrix for which numpy.linalg.det() does not give complete nonsense...

Comment: I can't speak for `det`, but there was a bug in one routine where lapack would return nonsense when you asked it "how much working memory will this operation take". Accelerate is pinned on lapack 3.2.1, so you could look at the lapack changelog to work out which bugs have been fixed since then.